# How to change textstyle to Material headline?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

How to changes text style Material headline?

```
Text("Lorem Ipsum",
      style = TextStyle() // ????
)
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [M2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material#typography) `TextStyle`s are accessed via `MaterialTheme.typography`

For example:

```
Text(
     text = "Lorem Ipsum",
     style = MaterialTheme.typography.h1
)
```

You can customize them in your theme. Something like:

```
val MyTypography = Typography(
    h1 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = Rubik,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W300,
        fontSize = 96.sp
    ),
    body1 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        fontSize = 16.sp
    )
    /*...*/
)
MaterialTheme(typography = MyTypography, /*...*/)
```

In [M3](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3#typography) the approach is similar. You can define your custom `TextStyle` in the Theme:

```
val replyTypography = Typography(
    titleLarge = TextStyle(
        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
        fontSize = 22. sp,
        lineHeight = 28. sp,
        letterSpacing = 0. sp
    ),
    titleMedium = TextStyle(
        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
        fontSize = 16. sp,
        lineHeight = 24. sp,
        letterSpacing = 0.15.sp
    ),
)

MaterialTheme(
    typography = replyTypography,
) {
    // M3 app Content
}
```

and then apply them:

```
Text(
    text = "Lorem Ipsum",
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge
)
```